# Suprema Biomini Slim2 Don't show the image correctly in the PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I am working with 2 scanner of biomini suprema :

- slim 2
- plus 2
  And its SDK v 3.7.5 .
  I use the next function to draw the image in the buffer

```
Graphics loGrafico = this.pbImageFrame.CreateGraphics();
Rectangle loRectangulo = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.pbImageFrame.Width, this.pbImageFrame.Height);

try
{
    toScanner.DrawCaptureImageBuffer(loGrafico, loRectangulo, true);
}
finally
{
    loGrafico.Dispose();
}
```

And use the next to update the image of my Picturebox-pbImageFrame

```
public void mxActualizarPictureBox(PictureBox toPictureBox, Image toImagen)
{
    if (toPictureBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        _UpdatePictureBox loDelegado = new _UpdatePictureBox(mxActualizarPictureBox);
        // Call the function in the correct thread
        BeginInvoke(loDelegado, new object[] { toPictureBox, toImagen });
    }
    else
    {
        // We are in the correct thread, so assign the image
        toPictureBox.Image = toImagen;
    }
}
public int CaptureEvent(object sender, UFScannerCaptureEventArgs e)
{        
    this.mxActualizarPictureBox(this.pbImageFrame, e.ImageFrame);
    return 1;
}
```

When I use the scanner plus2 the image show correctly but when I use Slim2 the image is displayed wrong:

[image: slim2_image]

Solve this problem with the possible solutions.

Comment: _"**solve this problem with the possible solutions.**"_ That's a little harsh; Is it a homework?